# Go through a set of images in an array on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to do a "sprite kind of animation" on mouseenter an image. The idea is to have the image "wink" once when we hover it.

i am trying to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var images = [];
   images[0] = "images/image0.png";
   images[1] = "images/image1.png";
   images[2] = "images/image2.png";
   images[3] = "images/image3.png";
   images[4] = "images/image4.png";

   var count = 5;

   $("img.talk-to-us").mouseenter(function(){
      count = 0;
   });

   if(count < 5) {
      $("img.talk-to-us").attr("src",images[count]).delay(1000);
   count++;
   }
});
```

What i would like to happen on mouseenter is that the images are changed in sequence, with a delay between each image. After the last image i would like it to stop (last image stays showing).

Any ideas on how to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make a gif out of your images and change the source on mouse over?

Comment: `delay()` jquery method is used for jquery animation. Use `setTimeout()` js function instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an approach for you:

```
$("img").mouseenter(function () {
    (function srcLoop(i) { // define a function (see IIFE)
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").attr("src", images[i]); //change the image src
                if (i > 0) {
                    i--; //decrement the counter
                    srcLoop(i); //recursivly call the function
                }
            }, 1000) //delay the function
    })(images.length - 1); //pass the length of the image-array as an argument (-1 because of the index starting at 0)
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b1La7e6j/)

**Reference**

[.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/setTimeout)

[IIFE - Immediatly Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)